# Is it illegal to set up a pretend speed camera or speed camera sign?

Tags: united-kingdom

[This story](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-nottinghamshire-40184757) about someone using a hairdrier as a fake speed camera made me think.

1. It's illegal to damage a speed camera.
2. It's illegal to put up an unofficial sign warning about speed cameras, or flash your lights to warn others of cameras.
3. Is it illegal to set up a pretend speed camera?

Suppose she'd got a bona fide sign or a plausible looking box, and set it up on her own property. Is that allowed?